# Create a line animation

Tags: animation, animated-gif

I haven't dabbled with animated gifs for a very long time. I'd like to create something similar to this:

https://dribbble.com/shots/2941889-Wind

I can't imageine whoever created this animated frame-by-frame to get that result. So i'd like to know what tools there are for doing something like that? Or perhaps i'm all wrong and the only way to do it is frame-by-frame?

Just some advice where to get started if anyone is able.

Answer (score 0):

So what i did in the end was use Adobe Illustrator to create the paths.

I then changed the stroke to dashed. Modifying the dash i was able to make it appear as thought the line was growing along the path. I then created more paths.

I then created a js file to incrementally increase the dash and save a gif. This created me over 100 snapshots.

Imported these into Adobe Photoshop and export! Bingo!